# How do you do examine a Google Chrome extension before installing it?

Tags: security, google-chrome, dropbox

I found what appears to be a very cool extension for Google Chrome - a [Dropbox addin that lets you compare versions of files in your Dropbox by using a diff tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aefdkgcdokdiaoppobphjogcilaaakka).

[image]

Like most Chrome extensions, this one has some warnings about permissions:

> This extension can access:
>
> - Your data on dropbox.com and www.dropbox.com
> - All data on your computer and the websites you visit

My default instinct is to download the source of the extension and look through it, but the only button I see is "Add to Chrome"

Since Google Chrome is supposed to be "open source," and there is a nice community repository for downloading extensions, I would have expected to see something like "download the source code."

**My questions are:**

- How do you download the source for an extension prior to installing it?
- What other ways can you "do your homework" and make sure an extension is safe besides
  looking at reviews and/or looking through the source code?

Comment: Please use the provided image uploader in the future when adding images to your questions and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Extension Gallery and Web Store Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbamfloeabgknfklmgbpjcgofcokhpia) extension that would show you source code and tell which features and API methods are used.

Comment: Does anyone else see the irony of this inspector? Hmm?

Comment: Obsolete link??