# Can Chrome extensions install other?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, virus, google-chrome-extensions

Is it real, that current installed in browser Chrome extensions can install other?
Or all extensions from Google Store are safe, and cant contain viruses?

Comment: You should still use caution when selecting extensions.  Even the tightest approval publishing process will miss something eventually.  You should only use extensions by authors you trust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Chrome extensions cannot install other Chrome extensions. They also cannot install any software (i.e., viruses) on your computer without your action.

Your main concern with extensions should be data privacy. See:

- [How can I be sure that a Google Chrome extension isn't doing evil things?](https://superuser.com/questions/666082/how-can-i-be-sure-that-a-google-chrome-extension-isnt-doing-evil-things)
- [How do you do examine a Google Chrome extension before installing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/337172/how-do-you-do-examine-a-google-chrome-extension-before-installing-it)

... in practice, the advice boils down to "use long-existing extensions from reputable publishers, with a large number of users".